# JOOQ : want to convert DSL to inline

Tags: jooq

I have a DSL like

```
DSL.case_().when(field.equal('5'), true).else_(false)
```

it is creating bind values..

and I don't want bind values.. (for some specific use cases.. bind values aren't working)

Using **DSL.inline** isn't solving this...

for the character-based field.

```
when "my field name" = ''1'' then false
  else true
```

How do I make it inline & it should be able to handle various field dataTypes?

Comment: Can you show your exact `DSL.inline()` usage, please?

Comment: DSL.inline(DSL.case_().when(field.equal('5'), true).else_(false))

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, I take that you're wrapping the entire expression with [`DSL.inline(T)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#inline(T)) for some reason, but that's not how it works. It doesn't take arbitrary expressions and forces its contents to be inlined. It just takes a *value* and inlines that, [see also the manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters/). So, in your case, it used your expression as a bind value (calling `toString()` on it).

What you want is to wrap each individual value with `DSL.inline()`, e.g.:

```java
when(field.eq(inline("5")), inline(true)).else_(inline(false))
```

Alternatively, you can globally [set `StatementType.STATIC_STATEMENT` to inline *all* bind values](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-statement-type/).

Comment: For a field with String dataType.. 

"my string based field name " = 5..

the SQL turns out like this. which doesn't work as it expects 5 in quotes

I have fields with two datatypes.. string short

Comment: @moovon: Well, I forgot the `"` around `"5"` (updated the answer). But is that still your question? Sounds like a different question now. At least it's unclear to me what you're trying to say...